# How can I create x = constant lines on a figure with adjacent labels (automatically)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some reference lines say x=1 and x=3 and to label each of those lines in the figure beside the line. I am aware this can be done by manually by specifying the position however for my case (I am plotting hundreds of these lines automatically) this is not plausible.

Is there a simple way to do this?

I have been trying to use a function found online with no luck.

Here is what I currently have: - filename contains a time series - Yan_S and Yan_T are both files containing values I want to plot and information for the associated labels.

```
################## DEFINE SPECTRAL PLOTTING ##################

# plot_spectra(filename, title, deltaT, taper_onoff)
# filename should include full path to .txt of amplitudes (no headers)
# title will be the title of the figure
# deltaT is the time smapling in seconds
# taper_onoff 1-on 0-off
# mode_label_onoff 1-on 0-off

 def plot_spectra(filename, title, deltaT, mode_label_onoff):
     signal = np.genfromtxt(filename)
     time_vector = np.arange(signal.size)*deltaT

spectra = np.fft.rfft(signal) # implement taper
freq_mHz = np.fft.rfftfreq(time_vector.size, deltaT)*1.e3
plt.ylabel(r'$\sqrt{P}$')
plt.xlabel('mHz')
#plt.plot(freq_mHz, abs(spectra.real))

# PLOT MODE LABELS
if mode_label_onoff != 0:
    Yan_S_Vals = Yan_S[4]
    Yan_T_Vals = Yan_T[4]
    Yan_S_Labels = ["" for x in range(len(Yan_S))]
    Yan_T_Labels = ["" for x in range(len(Yan_S))]

    for i in np.arange(0,len(Yan_S)):
        Yan_S_Labels[i] = str(Yan_S[0][i])+'S'+str(Yan_S[2][i])
        Yan_T_Labels[i] = str(Yan_S[0][i])+'S'+str(Yan_S[2][i])

    # Spheroidal Modes
    lineid_plot.plot_line_ids(freq_mHz, abs(spectra.real), Yan_S_Vals, Yan_S_Labels)
    # Toroidal Modes
    lineid_plot.plot_line_ids(freq_mHz, abs(spectra.real), Yan_T_Vals, Yan_T_Labels)

plt.xlim(0, 10)
#plt.savefig('/Users/Alex/Desktop/Python/'+title.split('.')[0]+'_spectra.svg')
plt.savefig('/Users/Alex/Desktop/Python/'+title.split('.')[0]+'_spectra.png')
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: How about using annotation? http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html